# Php Standalone Skript doesnt Query Database, APIv4 Simple Example

Tags: mysql, php, apiv4

I tried to write a Standalone PHP-Skript for CiviCRM and looked after the [Simple Example](https://learn.civi.be/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=h5p_embed&id=6), but unfortunately it doesnt return something.

```
<?php
require_once '/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/civicrm.config.php';
require_once $civicrm_root . '/CRM/Core/Config.php';


$config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();

$contacts = \Civi\Api4\Contact::get()
  ->addSelect('first_name')
  ->addWhere('contact_type', '=', 'Individual')
  ->setLimit(25)
  ->execute();

foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    echo $contact;
}
```

The variable $civicrm_root is loaded by the *civicrm.config.php* and is the absolute path to my civiCRM root: */var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/*.
I looked up both config files, they exist and I crosschecked the querycode against the APIv4 Explorer, and it works, I dont know what the problem is.

System:

- Debian 11 VM
- Apache 2.4.54
- PHP 7.4.30
- MariaDB: 10.5.15
- Wordpress: 6.0.1
- CiviCRM: 5.52.0
  I hope there is a Idea for a solution.
  Thanks in advance!

**Edit I**

I applied the suggestions and invoke it with ~/buildkit/bin/cv scr myscript.php but no return value either.

```
<?php
$config = CRM_Core_Config::singleton();

$contacts = \Civi\Api4\Contact::get()
  ->addWhere('contact_type', '=', 'Individual')
  ->setLimit(25)
  ->execute();

foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    echo $contact['first_name'];
}
```

**EDIT II**

I tried `cv api4 Contact.get +w 'contact_type = "Individual"' +l 25`
and it works, still: whats wrong with the script?

**EDIT III**

I insert the line  `echo count($contacts);`, and this return 0.

Comment: By default api4 enforces permissions. When run with `cv scr`, you either need to pass `--user=some_wordpress_username`  on the command line, or instead of `get()` use `get(FALSE)`. When run with `cv api4`, it seems to automatically bypasses permissions - this [appears to be on purpose](https://github.com/civicrm/cv/blob/88ce942e6bc5c08600cbe60b87d4a09973eabe69/src/Command/Api4Command.php#L27).

Comment: Did you see my comment above? You are getting 0 because you are running the script as the anonymous user who doesn't have access to contacts.

Comment: Yes Thanks! It was really helpful! I have to merge my new profile with my unregistred account to post this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do it that way. I'd remove those first two lines and install [cv](https://github.com/civicrm/cv) - if you are using buildkit you already have it - and then run it with `cv scr myscript.php`.

That way it runs on all cmses, and you can do other neat stuff like `cv scr --user=demo myscript.php` to run it as the user named demo to test different permissions, run it with `-vvv` to get some debugging, etc...

Separate note: $contact is not a string so you can't `echo` it. You can do something like `var_export($contact)`.

Answer (score 1):

In Combination out of Demerits posts i can solve the problem via

`cv scr --user=some_wordpress_username skriptname.php`

Thanks for the support.